# How to express "or" in a model Query?

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to query one of my models in a server script. I'm trying to use the [Query](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/server#Query) object for this, however, I don't see a way to formulate the conditions within the given API. What I need can be expressed in a [query language](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_builder) like this:

```
(FirstValue = :FirstValue or FirstValue = null) and (SecondValue = :SecondValue or SecondValue = null) and (ThirdValue = :ThirdValue or ThirdValue = null)
```

*(The goal is to query a lookup table based on several values. In the lookup table, `null` represents that this value isn't relevant and any value should be considered a match.)*

The `Query` class appears to support only `and` by specifying more than one filter, but there's no clear way to express `or`, is there? Or maybe there's a way to use the query language within the server script?

Using query script to fetch records in a UI element, reacting to `onLoad` and processing them there is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I know some ways to achieve desired result:

1. Using filters with with _contains:

```js
// Server Script
var query = app.models.MyModel.newQuery();

// should be resolved to true if 'someFilter' variable is null
query.filters.FirstField._in = [someFilter];

// all subsequent filters should be 'ANDed'
query.filters.SecondField._in = [someFilter];
query.filters.ThirdField._in = [someFilter];
...
var records = q.run();
```

2. Using 'where' query property:

```js
// Server Script
var query = app.models.MyModel.newQuery();

query.where = 'FirstField =? :parameter1 AND SecondField =? :parameter2 AND ...';
query.parameters.parameter1 = 'some value';
query.parameters.parameter2 = null;
...

var records = q.run();
```

3. Just putting where condition from the second option to datasource's query builder expression:

```js
// Query builder expression
FirstField =? :parameter1 AND
SecondField =? :parameter2 AND

...
```

then you can bind this query parameters to some widgets and load datasource on value change.

**Important:**

The **"?"** modifier for leaf operators considers a null value for the right-hand side of the expression to be true ([Query Builder](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_builder)).